How to sync non-wp database with wp-database?
I want to automatically sync some tables from remote non-WP MySQL to WP's MySQL. How can it be done in a Wordpress hosting?
I was talking to supporters of WP Migrate and DB Synchro, they mean, both plugins need WP on both ends.
Background:
On a remote VM runs a scraper, which daily populates a MySQL, on the same VM. The content of this DB I need in the WP database, to query it with wpDataTables. I can't create a remote DB connection with wpDataTables, due to company's security rules. So I need to anyhow automatically push the content of remote MySQL to Wordpress' MySQL.

the answer to this question will be hyper specific to your situation, I don't believe a general answer is possible, since you'll need to decide how the non-WP data maps into WP data structures/post types/users/terms/taxonomies/etc and some of those will be determined by what you're using it for and the business/use cases you're intending to have, as well as the nature of the data you're handling. Note that you rarely if never want to connect directly to a remote MySQL database as that implies it's open to the web which is a big security problem. You'll also want to know the direction of sync

What are you trying to do that requires this?

@TomJNowell I update my post with the background

usually if you need to fetch data you fetch it by talking to an API, or you expose an API that gets called, be that a dedicated application or REST API endpoints on your site that can be called. How you would "push" is going to be a question for the people who wrote the scraper app in the VM or manage that system since there'll be non-WP dev there. At the WordPress end once you have that data either because you made a request to a remote server to retrieve it, or it was given to you by that remote server in a request to you, you'd then need to store that data, most likely by using a table

of course the nature of the data, the timescales, and the size will determine what options are feasible, e.g. if your data is gigabytes then sending it in a single request won't be possible

As Tom J Nowell pointed out in the comments, this is a very specific situation, which makes the question rather difficult to answer.
If the source system has suitable code for pushing data to other systems, then you could consider registering a custom REST endpoint at the WordPress end. The endpoint would receive, validate and authorize the POST request from the other system. After passing all the necessary checks the request would then be processed and mapped in appropriate ways to fit the data structure used in WP.
The following functions might be used during the mapping, unless a custom database tables are used. In that case wpdb methods would probably be used.

wp_update_post()
wp_insert_post()
update_post_meta()
wp_insert_term()
wp_update_term()
wp_set_object_terms()
update_user_meta(), if the data is related to users

Another option is to pull the data from the other system, if it provides an API to do so. In this case you might use wp_remote_get() to request the data.
To schedule the data sync you can use WP Cron. Or if more robust background processing is required, you could consider using the action scheduler library (I'm not affiliated with action scheduler).
In either case, either pushing or pulling the data, the supporing code at the WP end would go into a custom plugin.
